What exactly is the issue with zero-values in compositional data and using the Dirichlet distribution?
So, Aitchison describes the problem of zero-values being that the log of these numbers cannot be taken. But he also explains that if there are only a small number of zeros, we can simply replace them with a small number. He cautions that the choice of such small values can impact results. I have two questions:

Why can't we just take the smallest number available (machine epsilon in R)?
Why can't this approach be used no matter how many zeros you have?

This paper is dated but has still been referenced recently to describe the problems associated with zero-values when modeling with a Dirichlet.
Thanks!

Machine epsilon ($2^{-52}\approx$ 2.220446e-16 in all the standard R installations) isn't the smallest number available: you can represent and take the log of much smaller numbers, right down to $2^{-1022}\approx$2.225074e-308 in the standard R installations. And that illustrates the problem. The 'smallest number' is seriously dependent on your implementation and your definition of smallest, to an extent that can affect your analysis.
To take a concrete example, I took 10 numbers from a uniform (ie, Beta(1,1), ie Dirichlet(1,1)) distribution and one zero, coded as either $2^{-52}$ or $2^{-1000}$ and maximised the Beta (ie, Dirichlet) likelihood
> x<-runif(10)
> x1<-c(2^-52,x)
> x2<-c(2^-1000,x)
> ell1<-function(theta) -sum(dbeta(x1,theta[1],theta[2],log=TRUE))
> ell2<-function(theta) -sum(dbeta(x2,theta[1],theta[2],log=TRUE))
> ell0<-function(theta) -sum(dbeta(x,theta[1],theta[2],log=TRUE))
> optim(c(1,1),ell0)$par
[1] 3.537810 2.284201
> optim(c(1,1),ell1)$par
[1] 0.2001339 0.4107025
> optim(c(1,1),ell2)$par
[1] 0.01405188 0.11391696


So even though no reasonable person would care about the difference between $2\times 10^{-16}$ and $9\times 10^{-302}$, the likelihood does care quite a bit.  If you use 0.1 instead of the very small values you get a much more reasonable MLE.
The real underlying issue is data genuinely from a Dirichlet distribution will not have zeroes, so that how to represent the zeroes you do have is a question of handling measurement imperfections or model misspecification. That's why it doesn't have a nice tidy answer like "machine epsilon"

Thank you. Honestly, I can't think of a scenario where the choice between 2^-1022 and 2^-100...etc. would affect the analysis.

It's not that, it's the difference between 1022 and 100 matters for maximum likelihood: see edit

ah okay this makes sense. Thank you.
